# Invert complete webpage colors and reverse them with single toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I need help to make this JSFiddle to reverse the color inversion I have tried many methods and tricks but failed somehow everytime.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/jVKw6/8/)

above is the link to the jsfiddle which I would like to use on my website the same button should reverse the function but it isn't doing so i think there is some kind of error in it.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not properly linked. Please provide the correct link and make it public.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `html` and `body` height and `white` background instead of transparent:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $("html").toggleClass("inversed");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.inversed {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Inverse</button>
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!! it worked and its the simplest form ever thank you very very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the style to the header, apply it directly to the `<html>` element. Then you can remove it again easily by putting something like this inside the `negativar` function:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');

if (html.getAttribute('style')) {
    html.setAttribute('style', '');
} else {
    html.setAttribute('style', 'YOUR STYLE HERE')
}
```